# Laravel snappy pdf --viewport-size 1024x768 wkhtmltopdf windows OS not work

Tags: laravel, wkhtmltopdf

`viewport-size`, this command not working in `windows OS`

Here is my config from laravel snappy pdf `config/snappy.php`

```
'pdf' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => '"C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe --viewport-size 1024x768"',
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => [],
    'env'     => [],
],
```

When I use above config, it shows an error like this:

> The exit status code '1' says something went wrong: stderr:
>   "'"C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe --viewport-size
>   1024x768"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. " stdout: "" command: "C:/Program
>   Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe --viewport-size 1024x768"
>   --lowquality

Any solution of this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You have to install wkhtmltopdf for windows with composer.

```
composer require wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows
```

```
'pdf' => array(
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary' => base_path('vendor/wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows/bin/64bit/wkhtmltopdf.exe'),
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => array(),
    'env'     => array(),
),
'image' => array(
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary' => base_path('vendor/wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows/bin/64bit/wkhtmltoimage.exe'),
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => array(),
    'env'     => array(),
),
```

Comment: Hi @Qonvex620 thanks for your answer

This case already solved when i added this command like this

 'binary'  => '"C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe" --viewport-size 1024x768',